# How can I know if my iPhone had been erased?

Tags: iphone, ios, find-my-iphone

My iPhone was lost 3 months ago and I have decided to erase my iPhone since then but until now I don't know if it erased or not. I'm still afraid that the thief may have access to my private stuff.

How can I know that my iPhone have been erased or can I track at least if it was already erase?

I tried to check my email and apple account and yet there is no mail.

Answer (score 4):

When the device is erased, you should receive an email notification informing you that the device has successfully been erased. This is regardless of whether the device was online or offline when you clicked Erase, since the next time the device is online the device will be erased and an email will be sent.

> - If your device is online, the remote erase begins. A confirmation email is sent to your Apple ID email address.
> - If your device is offline, the remote erase begins the next time it’s online.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/PH2701</sup>

You will be unable to track the device through Find My iPhone if you erase it.

> Note: If you erase your iPhone, you won't be able to use Find My iPhone to locate or protect it, but your Apple ID and password will be required to reactivate it.

<sup>Source: http://support.apple.com/kb/TI79</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your iPhone is connected to Find iPhone, on erasing you should receive an email stating it has been erased. If its offline( assuming its still connected with your apple account), it will erase as soon as it comes online next.

Login to your iCloud account, and go to Find my iPhone. click on the All Devices dropdown, It should show you the status of your phone. If it has been erased, it will not show in the list( Again, assuming it was the find my iPhone setting was enabled by you and wasn't disabled by the thief).

Comment: what if the thief erase or close the Find my iPhone app would it still work?

Comment: If you had iCloud setup, and your find my iPhone activated, then the thief would need to know your apple id and password to swtich it off. I am not sure if jailbreaking the phone messes this up or not.

Answer (score -3):

I dont think an erased iPhone can be compromised.